# Socket.io emit event returning different values

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am making an app with socket.io. I am trying to display the list of connected users in two different webpages. Here is my code -

Server.js file -

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

server = app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server running");
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

var users = [];

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('new-user',function(name){
        users.push(name);
        io.sockets.emit('user-connected',users);
    });
    socket.on('fetch-user-list',function(){
        io.sockets.emit('user-list',users);
    })
});
```

Now I have two HTML files each linked to a different js file -

file1.js -

```
var socket = io.connect();
const name = prompt('What is your name?');

socket.emit('new-user',name);
container = document.getElementById('container');

socket.on('user-connected',function(users){
    container.innerHTML = '';
    users.forEach(element => {
        const listElement = document.createElement('li');
        listElement.innerText = element;
        container.append(listElement);
    });  
});
```

So this prints out all connected users in its connected HTML page and is the desired output.

But when I try to use the **users** array from server.js again for the second js file like so -

file2.js -

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('fetch-user-list');
container = document.getElementById('container');

socket.on("user-list",function(users){
   console.log(users);
});
```

I get an empty users array. Are socket events page specific and somehow my users array gets reset to empty array after leaving the first page? Any help will be appreciated.

Note:- The second js file gets executed after the first.

Comment: you are making separate socket connections in each of your file1 and file2, so you will have different data on different pages.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there anyway I can use the same throughout all my pages?

Comment: reuse the single socket instance so that you do not need to reconnect it. export your socket variable.